# Convert a long String into String Array in Blackberry?

Tags: java, string, blackberry

I am working on a BB application in which I am getting a long String from server.
Now I want to convert that string in to String Array of words present in the String, so that i can compare the complete Array elements one by one with my hard coded fields and can display them for user.

Please let me know the with your useful suggestion.

Comment: Assuming words are split by whitespace, `String[] words = longString.split("\\s+");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split()` is not available for Java 1.3 (CLDC 1.1).

Did you already look at `net.rim.device.api.util.StringUtilities#stringToWords`?

Comment: split() function does not exist in Blackberry, i tried with substring but its also not working what i need.

Comment: Ah! didn't realize you are using RIM's JDK :(

Comment: Did you already look at net.rim.device.api.util.StringUtilities#stringToWords?